# Views: Filtering by latest of end dates in multi-value field collection

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type that contains a multi-value field-collection field (itineraries).  That field collection has another multi-value field collection field (legs).  The legs field collection contains a date field that collects a start and end date.

Is there anyway in views to filter items to show only nodes for which the latest end date (temporally, the actual latest on the calendar) on the node is later than some specific date?

Ideally I'd like to do it without some php embedded in the view itself, but  a solution with code in a custom module would be ok.

**Update** I'm still interested in a solution for this, but for now, I've gone back and gotten the ok to simplify the business logic, to allow be to use a much simpler filter, since this particular issue will only be relevant for about a month after the view is released.

Comment: If you add a relationship to your itineraries field, then add another relationship to your legs field that should now allow you to use the fields from the legs FC in the filters

Comment: Right, but how would I then filter against the latest of all the end dates?

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that, what do you mean by latest? Is that latest date item added or the next date value? If its the date value then just adding the normal date filter should act the same I think. If its the latest added I dont think you'll be able to do that without some custom work

Comment: There will possibly be multiple Itineraries with multiple legs in them, I want to get the temporally latest end date, and filter out any nodes for which that latest end date isn't after a certain specific date.  Will edit the question to clarify latest.